# How can I plot a 3D array in Matplotlib where the 3rd dimension contains the values for each position (x, y, z)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3D grid of data, formatted as a 3D numpy array (it is (41,300,300), as in (z,x,y)) that I want to create a 3D contour plot in Matplotlib with "contour3D", where the contour surface is for the values z in (x, y) that are above a threshold (say, above 1). In other words, all grid points that are above the threshold are contoured, essentially like a 3D version of "contourf". The problem I am running into is that the first axis (of length 41) contains the values for each 3D position (x, y, z). Usually when plotting a 3D surface, each element in a 2D array contains the z values (such as a (300,300) array).

Based on some research, it seems like the best solution would be to convert the 3D array into a 2D array where the new (x,y) values are are the indices of the z values above the threshold. I have tried converting the 3D array to 2D where the shape (300,300) is preserved and the values at each (x,y) pair is equal to the index in the first (z) axis of length 41 when the threshold is met and set to 0 (zero) when the threshold is not met. But, have not gotten anything working.

Another potential solution that I have come across is creating a "4D" version of contour3D where the color ramp is the function of (X, Y, Z) data. However, the surface itself would not be what I am trying to plot.

Is this possible in Python/Matplotlib?

I am not sure the best way to share this, but essentially w is data at (z,y,x).

```
z = [ 0.      ,  0.5     ,  1.      ,  1.5     ,  2.      ,  2.5     ,
        3.      ,  3.5     ,  4.      ,  4.5     ,  5.      ,  5.5     ,
        6.      ,  6.5     ,  7.      ,  7.5     ,  8.      ,  8.5     ,
        9.      ,  9.5     , 10.      , 10.500001, 11.000001, 11.500001,
       12.000001, 12.500001, 13.000001, 13.500001, 14.000001, 14.500001,
       15.000001, 15.500001, 16.      , 16.5     , 17.      , 17.5     ,
       18.      , 18.5     , 19.      , 19.5     , 20.      ]
x = np.linspace(-149.5,149.5,1)
y = np.linspace(-149.5,149.5,1)

# w is data at (z,x,y)
np.shape(w)
> (41, 300, 300)
```

Some attempted solutions:

```
x1, z1, y1 = np.meshgrid(dx, zf, dy)
```

But, that creates three 3D arrays.

```
for i in range(41):
    for j in range(300):
        for k in range(300):
            data[i,j,k] = i
```

This one gets all (z,x,y) values to be equal to (index of z, x, y), but this is still 3D. Further, I tried to "mask" (i.e., convert) each value above some threshold to the index of that value.

```
w_ar = np.array(w)

# Convert above and below threshold. Set above to -999.
wt = 0.01
w_ar[w_ar > wt] = -999
w_ar[w_ar < wt] = 0

# Convert all elements with value -999 to the values at that location from the index array "data".
w_ar[w_ar==-999]=data[w_ar==-999]
```

That produces a 3D array still and I'm not 100% it even works.

Finally, here is what I have that does not work for plotting.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
c3d = ax.contour3D(dx,dy,w_ar[:,:,:])
```

That returns error `TypeError: Input z must be 2D, not 3D` (as expected). I also tried with a loop:

```
for i in range(len(w_ar[:,0,0])):
    c3d = ax.contour3D(dx,dy,w_ar[i,:,:])
```

Plot is blank with this feedback: `UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.`. It appears w_ar broke somewhere above, so I recreated np.array(w):

```
war = np.array(w)
for i in range(len(war[:,0,0])):
    c3d = ax.contour3D(dx,dy,war[i,:,:])
```

This produced a plot, but does not match the goal output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdzMT.png)

This is my first post here, so please let me know if anything else is needed or changes to formatting, etc. Thanks in advance for any help! The ultimate goal would be to create something similar to the gray surface in this plot (after changing opacity, etc.). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r1Xm.png)